# Disable button when db is populated enable when null on javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, select

I have my database table named material
material:

```
mat_id    mat_name     status
1          bolts         
2          steel      approved
```

How can I make my button or maybe href link disable when status = 'approved'
on my html table?

like:

```
option        mat_id   material name
show button     1         bolts
no button       2         steel
```

my code for html/php:

```
    <?php 


    $resource=mysql_query("Select * from material",$con);

    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
        { 

        ?>
     <tr>
    <th>option</th>
    <th>mat_id</th>
    <th>material name</th>
    </tr>

     <tr>
  <td align="center">
<?php 
$id = $rows['reqraw_id'];
if($rows['status']=="")
{
   echo '<a href="addstockout.php?id=$id" > Update </a>';
} ?>
</td>
    <td><?php echo $result2['mat_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result2['mat_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php };?>
```

There is a problem on this line

```
echo '<a href="addstockout.php?id=$id" > Update </a>';
```

It doesn't get the id array from the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
<?php if($result2['status'] == 'approved') { ?>
    <td><button disabled="true">Button</button></td>         
<?php 
} else{ ?>
    <td><button>Button</button></td>
 <?php } ?>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

Instead of

```
<td>button</td>
```

put:

```
<?php

echo '<td><button ';
if(!($result2['status']==="approved"))
{
   echo 'disabled="true"';
}
echo '>Click</button></td>';

?>
```

Comment: OP wants it *enabled* if `status` is `null`. IE: `if($result2['status']===NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result2['status']=="" OR $result2['status']===NULL)
{
   echo '<button type="button">Click Me!</button>';
}else{
   echo '<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><?php echo ($result2['status']===NULL)?"button here":"disabled"; ?></td>
```

Comment: You should probably have asked this as a separate question rather than changing your original one but... `echo '<a href="addstockout.php?id='. $id. '" > Update </a>';`